# How to pass information through delegates from a keyboardviewcontroller to the main viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates, tableview

I have these two files, tab2 and KeyboardViewController. I am trying to create a delegate between these two files.

I have removed some of the necessary tableView functions for simplicity sake.

KeyboardViewController is linked to a storyboard called keyboard.storyboard
tab2 is linked to another storyboard called main.storyboard.

I want to send data from the list called Lines in KeyboardViewController to the file tab2 and append it into the list in that file.

My problem is that the program is running, but when i try to send the delegate from the KeyboardViewController to tab2, the tab2 file wont receive the data. (e.g. the print i have put in the textChoice function doesn't run at all)

I have tried to initiate the tab2 Viewcontroller in different ways, but to no prevail. Thank you for your time.

tab2.swift

```
import UIKit


class tab2: UIInputViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, icebreakerData {

    func textChoice(string: String) {
        print("textChoice is run")
        likedList.append(string)

    }

    var myVC = KeyboardViewController()

    var likedList: [String] = ["Hello there", "Hello there again"]

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!




        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
            tableView.dataSource = self
            tableView.delegate = self
            print("INITIATING THE VCs")
            myVC.iceBreakerDataDelegate = self


            // this code makes the app crash when i enter site in the app
//         let myVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tab2") as? KeyboardViewController
//         myVC?.iceBreakerDataDelegate = self
//         navigationController!.pushViewController(myVC!, animated: true)
//         self.present(myVC!, animated: true)
        }

}
```

KeyboardViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import UIKit.UIGestureRecognizerSubclass

protocol icebreakerData {
    func textChoice(string: String)
}

class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var iceBreakerDataDelegate: icebreakerData!
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!


        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
                 tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

                 let row = indexPath.row
                print("Sending text")
                 self.textDocumentProxy.insertText(Lines[row])

                print("DataDelegate sent")
                iceBreakerDataDelegate?.textChoice(string: Lines[row])

    }


    var Lines: [String] = [

        "First",

        "Second",

        "Third"

    ]

        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the reference. I can assume that `tab2` is your initial View Controller and you instantiate `KeyboardViewController` from that. Though you created

```
var myVC = KeyboardViewController()
```

but you may be presented/navigate `KeyboardViewController` from another object. like

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "keyboard", bundle: nil)
let VC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "KeyboardViewController") as! KeyboardViewController
VC.iceBreakerDataDelegate = self // in this object you should conform self
present(VC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

That's why you're getting nil.

Or if you're using segue then you can do something like this

```
if(segue.identifier == "YourSegueIdentifier"){
    let v = segue.destinationViewController as! YourViewController
    v.delegate =  self

}
```